# Multi Join on two tables not working in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I have an Issue with alias joins in access 2016.I have a table 'projects' that includes fields for Employer, End User, Purchaser. Each of these fields references the same table 'Client'.
I want to list Project name, Employer and Purchaser with this SQL:

```
SELECT Projects.[Project Name],A.Company as employer,B.company as Purchaser
FROM Projects INNER JOIN Clients as A ON Projects.Employer = A.ID
 INNER JOIN Clients B  ON Projects.Purchaser = B.ID;
```

I get an error:

> Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression Projects.Employer = A.ID
>    INNER JOIN Clients B  ON Projects.Purchaser = Clients.ID;

Can't work out what is going on as each individual join works fine but I get the error when I put them together!

Answer (score 0):

Access is a little strange on the kind of SQL it will accept, you definitely have to alter your syntax just a little bit for most things. I believe for multiple inner joins you need to add some parentheses

This should work:

```
SELECT Projects.[Project Name],A.Company as employer,B.company as Purchaser
FROM (Projects INNER JOIN Clients as A ON Projects.Employer = A.ID)
 INNER JOIN Clients B  ON Projects.Purchaser = B.ID;
```